# student passed all subject in atleast one attempt

Tags: sql

Consider a data below:

```
STUDENT_ID  SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG testnumber
123 YNYNNY  1
123 YNYNYY  2
123 NNNYNN  3
456 YYYYYY  2
789 YNYNYN  1
789 NYNYNY  3
```

Expected Output:

```
STUDENT_ID  SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG
123 YNYYYY
456 YYYYYY
789 YYYYYY
```

Each character in SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG indicate the result of each subject and test number indicate the sequence number the test was attempted.

We want to find the final result as , if the student passed in atleast one attaempt in the subject then set flag as Y else N

Comment: OK. great.  What have you attempted?

Comment: and tag your database

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't mention which database you use. I try it in sql-server 2019.

I can only come up solution if you **have separator** in SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG string.

**schema**

```sql
CREATE TABLE data
(
    STUDENT_ID [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    testnumber int NOT NULL,
);
```

**table**

```sql
insert into data values
('123', 'Y,N,Y,N,N,Y',  1),
('123', 'Y,N,Y,N,Y,Y',  2),
('123', 'N,N,N,Y,N,N',  3),
('456', 'Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y',  2),
('789', 'Y,N,Y,N,Y,N',  1),
('789', 'N,Y,N,Y,N,Y',  3)
```

**sql**

```
select 
STUDENT_ID, 
STRING_AGG(case when total>0 then 'Y' else 'N' end, ',') WITHIN group ( order by num asc) as SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG 
from (
  select STUDENT_ID, num, sum(case value when 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as total 
  from (
    select 
    STUDENT_ID,
    value, 
    (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION by STUDENT_ID order by STUDENT_ID asc)-1)%6+1 as num
    from data  
    cross APPLY STRING_SPLIT(SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG, ',')
  ) as q
  group by STUDENT_ID, num
) as p
group by STUDENT_ID
```

**result**

```
STUDENT_ID  SUBJECT_PASSING_FLG
123         Y,N,Y,Y,Y,Y
456         Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
789         Y,Y,Y,Y,Y,Y
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=63b8da038c44bca16291dfe97c697c0e)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have found exact one

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into dataval values
(1,'YYNY',1),
(1,'YNNY',2),
(1,'NYNY',3),
(2,'YNNY',1),
(3,'YNNY',1),
(4,'YNNY',3),
(3,'YYNY',2),
(4,'YNYY',3);
```

```
WITH cte_seq AS (
  SELECT 1 AS seq
  UNION ALL
  SELECT seq + 1 AS seq FROM cte_seq WHERE  seq < 4
), cross_cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM cte_seq CROSS apply dataval
), flag_wise_status AS (
  SELECT student_id,
         testnumber,
         Substring(subject_passing_flg, seq, 1) AS subject_status,
         seq AS subject_num
  FROM cross_cte
), max_flag AS (
  SELECT student_id,
         subject_num,
         Max(subject_status) AS subject_status
  FROM flag_wise_status
  GROUP BY student_id, subject_num
)
SELECT student_id,
       String_agg(subject_status, '') AS result
FROM   max_flag
GROUP  BY student_id;
```

Result:

```
1   YYNY
2   YNNY
3   YYNY
4   YNYY
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea493d7241be543386e62dea7db730c3)